# Error: Invalid callback() argument in Mongoose Update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and Mongoose. I have user collection. In that I have to insert or update based on the userid that is email.

I have used the following query

```
 var query={"userid":req.body.user_id, 
        "email":req.body.email,         
         "firstname":req.body.first_name,
         "lastname":req.body.last_name,
         "mobilenumber":req.body.phone_number};

db.update(query, {$set: {userid: req.body.user_id }}, {upsert:true},
         function(err,doc){

            if(err) {
                response = {"MethodName":"RegisterUser","isFault" : true,"ResponseData" : "Error adding data"};
            } 
            else {
                response = {"MethodName":"RegisterUser","isFault" : false,"ResponseData" : "User Registration completed successfully"};
            }
    }); // Added this here. Check your code if it is missing.
```

But this throws me Invalid callback argument error.

When I remove `{upsert:true}`, I am getting no error.But data not getting updated.When I add `{upsert:true}`, I got the following error,
Error I am getting.

```
Error: Invalid callback() argument.
at Query.update (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2062:13)
at Function.update (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1986:13)
at model.update (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:429:34)
at /var/www/html/chymnee/server.js:39:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Function.handle (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
at router (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /var/www/html/chymnee/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to use `db.userCollection.update` instead of using `db.update`

Comment: Also you have not added `});` in the end of `db.update(....`. Check if that is present in your code.

Comment: Here db is instance of mongodb class, var db = new mongoOp();I have missed to add }); at the end here.

Comment: Can you console `err` before `if(err)` and check. What is the error exactly says?

Comment: Look into the [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2901). This may give you some idea.

Comment: That cast error has been fixed. Thanks for the link. But Now Invalid callback argument error getting. Please see updated error in my question.